# Prevent page scrolling using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an app using Bootstrap.

The panels automatically grow so the user has to scroll their browser window down, I don't want this to happen.

Here is how it looks at the moment:

[image]

[image]

I want the Chat panel to be the complete height of the browser, so that the input box and send button is at the bottom of the browser, and I want the user list to grow to the current browser window size only, and then the scrolling to happen within it.

Is it possible using CSS?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <strong>Room:</strong> <span id="channel"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Chat</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul id="messages"></ul>
          <form id="chat">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chat-input" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="list-group" id="users"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow-y`? Show the code?

Comment: @Jack, does it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Clicking on the button, you generate something. You can also type and send something. The chat window has it's own scroller. Use the full screen preview. Also since I used the `scrollTop()`, it always scrolls to the last message.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  var sendChat = function () {
    $(".input-area .chat-area ul").append(($(".message-box").html().length) ? '<li style="display: none;" class="just-inserted">' + $(".message-box").html() + '</li>' : '<li style="display: none;" class="just-inserted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto optio culpa eum, hic recusandae temporibus earum consequatur laudantium esse itaque unde, vero! Sunt delectus debitis, alias reiciendis necessitatibus consectetur voluptatem.</li>');
    $(".message-box").html("");
    $(".input-area .chat-area ul li.just-inserted").slideDown(function () {
      $(".input-area .chat-area").scrollTop($(".input-area .chat-area ul").height());
      $(this).addClass("next-insert");
      setTimeout(function () {
        $(".next-insert").removeClass("next-insert just-inserted");
      }, 500);
    });
  };
  $(".input-area button").click(sendChat);
  $(".message-box").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      sendChat();
  });
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: Segoe UI;}
.input-area {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px 350px 15px 15px;}
.input-area .message-box {border: 1px solid #999; margin: 10px 0; padding: 5px;}
.input-area button {padding: 3px 15px; cursor: pointer;}

.input-area .chat-area {position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 10px; width: 325px; border: 1px solid #999; margin: 10px 10px 0; padding: 10px; overflow: auto;}

.input-area .chat-area ul li {margin: 5px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; transition: background-color 0.5s ease;}

.just-inserted {background: #ccc;}
.next-inserted {background: #999; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div class="input-area">
  <p>Enter Message Here</p>
  <div contenteditable class="message-box"></div>
  <button>Send</button>
  <div class="chat-area">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto optio culpa eum, hic recusandae temporibus earum consequatur laudantium esse itaque unde, vero! Sunt delectus debitis, alias reiciendis necessitatibus consectetur voluptatem.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also fade out the new message that has got posted by the way. Have a try above.

Comment: @Jack When did you *fishing* add your code? After I have given the answer?

Comment: When person asked, above?

Comment: @Jack Okay your question of having the left side bar and right side scrollable content is answered here right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You may force chat and users divs to have their own scrolls.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.chat {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
.users {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #f00;
}
.tempHeight {
  width: 100px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="tempHeight">Chat</div>
</div>
<div class="users">
  <div class="tempHeight">User list</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more of your markup I can only post some help

When I want things to be full height, I set the page to know this first

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
```

And then the elements (if they are direct children of the body) can use this

```
.chat {
    height:100%; /* You may have to use some more appropriate working out here with the help of calc() maybe */
    overflow: auto /* this will allow the scroll to happen in element not in window */
}
```

This would be using markup similar to this

```
<html>

<body>
    <div class="chat">
    This is the chat
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```